# how to move file after reading the file in ibm datastage

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

i have 1 folder which has 4 files, they are `sales_jan, sales_feb, debt_jan, debt_feb`.I created specific job for each sales and debt. The thing is, if i already run the job previously for `sales_jan` only and then there comes `sales_feb` after that, i dont wanna repeat reading the `sales_jan` again, i only want to read the newest file added that hasn't been processed. For reading the file, i pass the pattern of the specific file (ex. `sales_*`) but if i use it like that, then the stage will reprocessed the `sales_jan` again although it already has. I want to move the file already been read into another folder. How do i exactly do it in `ibm datastage`? if there's no way to do it, what's your suggestion for my problem. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use an after-job subroutine (ExecSH on Linux/UNIX, ExecDOS on Windows) to move the file to a different location.
Since you're using wildcards for the Sequential File stage, you're going to have to be a bit more clever in handling a situation where your job processes only some of the files. I would prefer to write this using a loop in a sequence, processing one file at a time, so that the move can be handled per-file.

Comment: but if i loop it then i need to write all of the file names, i'm making all of the job to be automatic without any interventions of the user since the user only want to click the run icon without editing anything (since they don't understand the tool).

Answer (score 0):

you might make a flag for every file which already read by your job. For example add a maxdate field for each file. When the first file max date is less than the second file or new file Then read the latest file. It can be done by using simple linux command in sequence or tranformer. Just like Ray mentioned before